# Catching Runtime Exceptions in 3rd party code

Tags: java, runtimeexception

I have developed a framework which allows other people to plug-in different implementations of optimizers. These optimizers are run asynchronously and I have attached listeners to run before and after inside the asynchronous code to monitor the execution of the optimizer. For example:

```
public void async(Optimizer o){
   runListeners(o);
   o.run();
   runListeners(o);
}
```

My problem is that some lazy programmer is throwing a some `NullPointerExceptions` inside their code and preventing the method from executing the listeners for the second time. I thought about catching `RuntimeException` but this feels wrong to me.

Comment: If you want to catch all, simply catch all `Throwable` or at least `Exception`. That's not wrong at the top/scheduling/running level of your program.

Comment: I am trying not to cause the JVM to misbehave. Like if there is a OutOfHeapspace or some other really bad error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you create a framework for plugins to run you have to consider how to handle exceptions thrown by the plugins, because you usually don't want a badly behaved plugin to crash your whole program. There is nothing wrong with catching Exception, RuntimeException, or maybe even Throwable here (though an Error might still be cause for aborting).

Comment: @user673289: it's a judgment call. for me it would depend on if I want to try to recover from something throwing Error. Maybe pick and choose which you can deal with.

Answer (score 0):

```
runListeners(o);
try {
  o.run();
} finally {
  runListeners(o);  // this will get run even if you get NPE
  // now your program crashes with the NPE :)
}
```